# how to compile sbopenurl (c)

Tags: objective-c, ios

im to trying to compile [sbutils](https://github.com/comex/sbsutils). it comes with a makefile but it errors out every time i try to compile it. this is the makefile:

```
BINS := sblaunch sburlschemes sbopenurl sbbundleids
all: $(BINS)
%: %.c ent.plist
     igcc -o $@ $< -std=gnu99 -framework CoreFoundation -framework SpringBoardServices
     ldid -Sent.plist $@
clean:
    rm -f $(BINS)
```

it comes with a few utils (sblaunch sburlschemes sbopenurl and sbbundleids) but i only want sbopenurl i try to complie it directly useing `gcc sbopenurl` but errors with

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_CFURLCreateWithBytes", referenced from:
      _main in ccMCI3Fd.o
  "_SBSOpenSensitiveURLAndUnlock", referenced from:
      _main in ccMCI3Fd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the prefixes of the symbols that the linker can't find, or if you just have look at the original Makefile, you can find out that the frameworks CoreFoundation and SpringBoardServices are neccessary. Further examination of either the sources or the Makefile will disclose that C99 extensions are used in the code therefore the -std=gnu99 flag will be needed for gcc. So compile using:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -framework CoreFoundation -framework SpringBoardServices -o sbopenurl sbopenurl.c
```

Comment: ok great thanks but every time i run the command it cant find CoreFoundation should it be in the direcory sbopenurl.c is in or in usr/inculude im useing gcc on my iphone btw :) thanks

Comment: nope... CoreFoundation is a standard Apple framework residing in <sysroot>/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework. If GCC can't find it, add the switch -isysroot <sysroot> to GCC's above command line. Substitute the iOS development sysroot to <sysroot>; it will probably be something like /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk (I don't know the exact path, I don't have Mac OS X).

Comment: Btw, it CAN'T be in /usr/include. The above 'compiler error' is not really a compiler error, but a linker error. It's not the case that the compiler can't find the declarations of these functions, but it can't find their actual implementation without the frameworks they're contained in. See this to understand how compiling works: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora065.html